# php call php file as image outside public directory

Tags: php, directory, get, private

In directory privateimgdir outside public directory I have file create_img.php that creates a png image on the fly. I need to serve that img from outside the public dir to avoid other sites to directly access the output image.

To do so, I'm trying to use a php proxy script. Inside public_scripts directory I have the file take_img.php with code as follows:

```
<?php

$file_to_get = basename(urldecode($_GET['file']));

$private_image_dir = "../../privateimgdir/";

$contents = file_get_contents($private_image_dir . $file_to_get);

header('Content-type: image/png');

echo $contents;

?>
```

Now I try to call take_img.php script and to pass create_img.php filename as a parameter by using this code:

```
echo "<a href='public_scripts/take_img.php?file=create_img.php'></a>";
```

But I get no output. Where am I wrong?

Comment: 1) file_get_contents won't execute the PHP, it'll just fetch the code. Use `include` or `require` instead. 2) If other sites want to use your image, they can just visit `public_scripts/take_img.php?file=create_img.php` instead, just like your own page does. Unless you make `take_img.php` require some kind of authentication check, then you haven't secured anything, you've just over-complicated your code by dividing one piece of functionality into two scripts.

Comment: P.S. "other sites linking to my images" is often called "hotlinking", if you google "how to prevent hotlinking" then you can find lots of advice on preventing it (if you prefer not to go down the authentication route in PHP). e.g. you can often enforce it through Apache .htaccess files, and other techniques.

Comment: Yes, to make long story short I omitted the part of take_imp.php code that authenticates the call, and the part of the origin page that assembles what's needed for authentication (there are many ways, sessions and db etc). About include, do I pass parameter to an include file the same way?

Comment: well the best thing to do would be for the code inside the included create_img.php file to be inside a function, which accepts the parameter. Then once you've included the file, you can just call the function.

Comment: Can you write an example of code?

Comment: `include $private_image_dir."create_img.php"; createImage();` (assuming that there is a `function createImage()` in your create_img.php). Actually now I think, you mention a parameter but I don't know which parameter you mean? It seem you always want the create_img.php file. Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: I have different target files in different page positions, each one making the job of create_img.php but with different image outputs. So for simplicity let's say that the only filename to pass is create_img.php. And yes the parameter is the filename. For security reasons I don't passo codes or other secret parameters through a GET, and instead I use sessions and db for the dirty job. But now is me that's a bit confused: your suggested code is to be used in take_img.php?

Comment: yes it would go in take_img.php. So...why have you got different scripts to generate images? Unless these scripts contents are very very different in each case, it would make more sense to have a single `function createImage($imageType)` and then you just use the `$imageType` variable to slightly vary what kind of image is returned. Maybe that's an oversimplification, but you get the idea. Repeating code which is likely to be quite similar (or at least has a very similar purpose) in multiple files is generally a poor design - you should try to write the same code only once.

Comment: Generally speaking you were right, but in this case any file produces a very complex plot of data onto different maps and in different graphics, with data coming from different dbs on different purposes, so it would have been a nightmare to assempble everything in a gigantic file with too many conditions and behaviours. The parts of code that are in common are obviously optimized and come from includes and requires in many places without repeating code.

Comment: ok well that's fair enough. Ok so if you're going to specify the filename in the $_GET parameter like you do now, then that's a security risk - you're effectively allowing the user (even an authenticated one) to execute any arbitrary code potentially on your system. Better to input an image type ID (or similar) in the URL (e.g. `<a href='public_scripts/take_img.php?type=1'></a>`) then use a switch statement to choose the correct file to include based on that. Then you're basically whitelisting the allowed values.

Comment: Good suggestion to use a type ID or similar (maybe a set of arbitrary codes), but to follow a little more your focus on security, how would you sanitize the input from a  $_GET parameter?

Comment: well if it's just a numeric ID, then it's easy - as I said, use a switch statement with cases for all your recognised IDs. If the GET value doesn't match any of those, it'll fall through to the "default" case and you can either return an error, or an empty result, or whatever you think is appropriate. It's a really straightforward whitelisting technique.

Comment: I've added a sample answer which I think meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) file_get_contents won't actually execute your PHP, it'll just return the raw source code from that file as a string. You want to be using `include` or `require` to make the script part of your main script and therefore be parsed and executed.

2) Don't accept a filename through the `$_GET` parameters directly - this is a security risk. It allows a user to potentially execute any arbitrary script on your system. Even if you're authenticating your users, you can't trust that any given user isn't either malicious or the victim of some kind of identity theft, social engineering, and/or virus/malware/bot on their device.

Here's a solution where you pass an arbitrary ID in the GET parameter, which will be more secure because you can whitelist the allowed options, and still allows you to choose the correct script to execute.

Firstly your HTML link tag would look something like this:

```
<a href='public_scripts/take_img.php?id=1'></a>
```

The take_img.php would look like this:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$private_image_dir = "../../privateimgdir/";
$script = "";

switch ($id) {
  case 1:
    $script = "create_img.php";
    break;
  case 2:
    $script = "someotherscript.php";
    break;
  case 3:
    $script = "yetanotherscript.php";
    break;
  default:
    throw new Exception("Invalid ID");
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
require_once $private_image_dir.$script;

?>
```

(N.B. it's assumed that the included PHP script will echo the content.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214382/discussion-on-answer-by-adyson-php-call-php-file-as-image-outside-public-directo).